# Read file-system into dataset

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a provider I can use to query the file-system and get the contents into a dataset?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about how you want the "file-system query" to be done. The file system is a tree structure, how do you want this to translate into a dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the classes that one might need to *query the file system* (whatever this means) are situated in the [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) namespace.

Depending on the *querying* you need there are classes like:

- [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)
- [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx)
- ...

There are useful methods such as [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) for example.

As far as the DataSet part is concerned, well, I guess once you have *queried* you could easily turn the results into a DataSet using LINQ.